# Adding header in sidenav using angular material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, responsive, sidenav

[image: Example image]

I need help in achieving sidenav like the above image.I have tried some steps to add using Mat-toolbar, but not sure how to add header and bring the other list below it. Like in the image, profile as header and details,activity,releases below it.
Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ve3igg

Thank you.

Comment: Check this page out - https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview

Comment: @LloydNicholson That documents various list-styles, but there's no Material component for a non-list-item textual heading _between_ lists.

Answer (score 0):

you Should Write the code in between side-nav-container not in mat-drawer-container
if ur Requirement is side-nav ;

```
   <mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
      <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened" >
      <h1 class="bg-primary"> Header</h1>
    <hr>
    <ul class="pull-right">
      <li> first Element<li>
      <li> second Element<li>
      <li> first Element<li>

      </ul>
      </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Here is the Stackblitz  demo with some dummy text with your requirement:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/rmbjojbnxvk

for Your knowledge:https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api